# Permission denied when uploading image to Amazon S3 with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, devise, paperclip

I am using Devise for account management and Paperclip to upload images to Amazon S3. Devise is working fine, but when I try to upload an image, it get the following error:

```
Errno::EACCES in Devise::RegistrationsController#update
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /users/avatars
```

Here is my code:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :confirmable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_attached_file :avatar, 
                    :bucket => ENV["S3_BUCKET"],
                    :url => ':s3_domain_url',
                    :path => '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
                    :styles => { 
                      :square => '200x200'
                    }, 
                    :default_url => "missing_avatar.png"


  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

I'm configuring Paperclip with

```
config.paperclip_default = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

And allowing `:avatar` with

`devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, ..., :avatar) }`

If I take the leading slash out of the `:path` option in `has_attached_file`, the error doesn't get thrown, but the image also doesn't get uploaded.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Try adding the `region` key-value pair to the `s3_credentials`: `region: ENV['AWS_REGION']`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help either. Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, very simple answer:

```
Errno::EACCES in Devise::RegistrationsController#update
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /users/avatars
```

was being thrown when Paperclip was trying to write to the local filesystem (was never using s3). `:storage => :s3` was never doing anything because I had `paperclip_default` instead of `paperclip_defaults`. Dang it.